# Eclipse like functionality on Vim without using eclim

Tags: vim

I quite like eclipse's ability to provide context support, refactoring, and also syntax check. Was wondering if there are plugins that could make vim more eclipse like.

Comment: What particular features are you interested in? Do you have some languages in mind? ... syntax check for example, for python - check out pyflakes...

Comment: Its called EMACS ;)

Comment: like I said, context support, refactoring, and on the go syntax check. C, Java, Python, Ruby, PHP, HTML, Javascript...

Comment: @chutsu - Uuhm ... I'm afraid you'll have to be a bit more explicit than that. "Refactoring", for example, is not a feature per se. Nor is "coding". Also, "context support"? What is context support in HTML for example?

Comment: Did you browse the plugins at www.vim.org, btw? Saw anything you like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure turning Vim into an IDE is a good or even realistic idea but you should google around for "vim as IDE": I've seen a lot of blogposts targeting PHP or Python or C++… they all come down to installing quite a lot of plugins. Since you want IDE-like support for many languages you will need to install many many plugins, most of them found on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org).

- I don't know what you mean by "context support". Do you want to display the documentation for the word under the cursor or is it something different?
- I don't know of a refactoring plugin that does everything. There are a few on vim.org but they seem to be limited to a couple of languages. If your needs are limited to changing variable names Vim has all you need and more built-in. Even things like "local variable to parameter" can be done easily with macros.
- There is a very nice syntax checking plugin called [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) that supports most of the languages in your list but not Java IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding refactoring, I've started a generic [refactoring plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhRefactor).

It's mainly aimed at C++, but it should also be possible to tweak it to support other languages. So far, it supports: Extract Function, Extract Variable, Extract Type, Extract Getter & Extract Setter.

Comment: Don't hesitate to leave me comments, new requirements, or even to patch the code for your language(s).

Comment: Hé hé, let's start with this: could you put it on vim.org?

Comment: I've stopped putting things up there because of the dependencies, and my wish to never release undocumented things in vimball/on vim.org. Unfortunately, the refactoring plugin depends on two completely undocumented library-plugins (lh-dev and lh-tags) which require an important documentation effort.

Comment: I understand your concerns.